# Retrieving executed tasks from Celery Scheduler?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I'm using Python 3.6.6, with the latest versions of Redis, Celery, Celery Beat and Celery Redbeat.

I'm currently using Celery redbeat to schedule periodic execution of tasks. Everything is working correctly, however I do not see an obvious way to link the tasks the scheduler executes, so I can retrieve their results.

For example the task run by the scheduler shows in redis as 'celery-task-meta-(task-id)'. Within the task or the scheduler I see nothing linking them. I know I can specify the 'options' argument and supply a dict of arguments to modify the task execution, however nothing stands out. I'm looking for a way to either change the 'celery-task-meta' to a value that corresponds with the scheduler name or an option that would propagate the completed task information to the scheduler. I feel I may be overlooking something obvious and would appreciate input.

In the output below I am interacting directly with the redis broker using the python redis library:

```
>>> entry = RedBeatSchedulerEntry('nameoftask', 'tasks.test', interval, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, app=app, options={'dict of apply_async arguments'})
>>> r.hkeys('redbeat:nameoftask')
[b'meta', b'definition']
>>> r.hget('redbeat:nameoftask', 'meta')
b'{"last_run_at": {"__type__": "datetime", "year": 2018, "month": 10, "day": 2, "hour": 2, "minute": 9, "second": 42, "microsecond": 79758}, "total_run_count": 5}'
>>> r.hget('redbeat:nameoftask', 'definition')
b'{"name": "nameoftask", "task": "tasks.test", "args": [...], "kwargs": {...}, "schedule": {"__type__": "interval", "every": 360.0, "relative": false}, "enabled": true}'
>>> r.get('celery-task-meta-19ec44ba-3440-4f9f-9e0a-7fce2b59de13')
b'{"status": "SUCCESS", "result": {"current": 100, "total": 100, "status": "Task completed!", "result": {"task output": "result"}}, "traceback": null, "children": [], "task_id": "19ec44ba-3440-4f9f-9e0a-7fce2b59de13"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was unable to find any mechanism using the redbeat scheduler. I ended up creating a child class of the RedbeatEntryScheduler that when due_next() is called it checks for the existence of a key correlating to the name of the RedbeatSchedulerEntry object and then appends the generated task's id to that key/value pair.

From Redis' perspective it looks like this:

```
>>> r.hget(b'redbeat:<task-name>-tasks', 'executed_tasks')
b'["d037db29-ef2c-4227-b7d3-6d19dc6ed68c", "ca4c509f-874f-4d87-80f1- 
dcaf3f5f2fa0", "89733f21-272e-485f-b6b9-55dbdfd07fca"]'
```